# Could Not Connect XMPP Server with smack : EOF Exception when implementing GCM XMPP-based App Server

Tags: java, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, smack

```
java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</mechanisms></stream:features>... @1:344
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3035)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:279)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

//resources : https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement

I have tried the exact code which is given in the android website, but it is throwing the end of file exception which i am thinking as some bug in MXParser(not quite sure though). If smack XMPP library is the problem, Is there any other xmpp library which i can use for GCM CCS ? Could any one please help me fix this . In the below image you can see the end stream tag is not closed but this is how i am receiving the packets.

sent and received packets 
Output windows:

[image: sent packets]

[image: received packets]

Comment: Can you please provide me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, I have restarted the machine and it got fixed by itself

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is described [here](http://qnalist.com/questions/5186334/gcm-ccs-connection-issue-after-a-lomg-period-of-time):

> You need to send some heartbeat - either at XMPP or TCP level - so your
>   endpoint can detect (or prevent) the closed TCP.
>   Many router/NATs fail to send RST or FIN, just drop the TCP connection.

For example, you may use [PingManager](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ping/PingManager.html) ([smack-extensions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.igniterealtime.smack/smack-extensions)) to implement such a heartbeat.