# java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream>

Tags: java, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am working on a chat app using xmpp,As per our requirement we have three server Apache Tomcat 7,ejabbered 2.1.11 and mysql 5.5,

```
to run xmppbot on tomcat  used below library
    -Smack-core-4.0.3.jar
    -smack-tcp-4.0.3.jar
    -xlightweb2.5.jar
    -xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar
    -xSocket-2.4.6.jar
```

Using above library I am able to Connect with ejabberd and able to login with my login id and password but after some time of logging in connection gets close automatically and a am getting below stack trace

```
Sep 16, 2014 4:36:01 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</text></error></iq>... @1:1347
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2919)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:2928)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1112)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1061)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:279)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:47)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:81)
Sep 16, 2014 4:37:15 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</text></error></iq>... @1:1347
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2919)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:2928)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1112)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1061)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:279)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:47)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:81)
```

and above messages keeps repeating in loop in my eclipse console!!!

can anyone explain me

1. What is the reason for the above error?
2. How can I solve above error?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: in my use case reason for occurrence of above error was jabber server(ejabberd) was dropping connection after a fixed time interval ofcause when connection was ideal,so what i did was after completing my task say sending chat message i am disconnecting the xmpp connection[my usecase was i was creating a xmpp connection from a servlet which runs on Tomcat7 application server] this was one solution another one is as mention by @Flow you can place a connection listener on created xmpp connection object,it will listen to connection Closed With Error and you can try to reconnect to xmpp server!

Comment: I am not experienced in ejabberd but possibly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27659800/2111944) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What is the reason for the above error?

Then connection went down unexpectedly. For example because the server closed it in an unclean way.

> 2. How can I solve above error?

There can be many causes for this. You should handle the exception and re-establish the connection.

Comment: Hiiii, I got same problem with ejabberd. We have recently migrated from openfire to ejabberd. We never came across this issue while using openfire. Any idea where to look at.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a heartbeat(ping) interval to overcome timeouts over idle connections. Timeouts need not necessarily be in the applications, they can be in the routers/switches in the path.in the example, 600 represents 10 minutes.

PingManager.getInstanceFor(connection).setPingInterval(600);